# Intersection-Observer in <Header /> not working as expected when changing page with vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, intersection-observer

I am trying to change my `<Header />` component's background colour, when it is over a `section`/`article` of my webpage (Single Page App).

[LINK](https://codesandbox.io/s/intersection-observer-li9vwd?file=/src/App.vue) to my app.

For this, I am using an Intersection-Observer which is located in my `<Header />`. It is searching for the `class="observer"` and when they intersect, the background colour changes.

However, when I use vue-router and go to another page and then back to where I was (via `@click="$router.push('/home#footer')"`, the Intersection-Observer stops working.

My guess is, that the components are not loaded yet and that's why the `background-color` of my `<Header />` ain't changing, but am not sure about it.

I had a similar problem when I started/refreshed my page. The observer seemed to load quicker than my other components. That's why I put him into a:

```
mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.activateObserver()
    }, 500)
  },
```

which for me just feels like bad practice, but have no other idea, on how to solve it.

I could reproduce my issue (sorry for the beautiful styles) on codesandbox: [LINK](https://codesandbox.io/s/intersection-observer-li9vwd?file=/src/App.vue)

How to reproduce:

1. Go to the linked page
2. Click on the badly styled burger
3. Click on the "about" btn on the appeared sidebar
4. When on the "about" page click again on the burger
5. When the sidebar appears again, click on the "contact" btn
6. Now when you slide on the page, the header's background colour isn't changing anymore.

Comment: You already knew the culprit. So to ensure that the element you want to observe exists, you can move your observer logic into the `mounted` hook of your `Content.vue` component. Don't forget to [disconnect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/disconnect) the observer on unMounted hook

Comment: Thanks for the clue. But what if I would have like 6 articles and would like to change the background of the <Header /> 3 times?

Comment: I have updated my sandbox so that you could see easier what I mean (cannot edit anymore)

Comment: If you have 3 Content components, just put the observer logic in the `mounted` hook of the `Content1.vue`. If you load the content from `v-for` you can put the observer logic to the `mounted` hook of the `Home` component after fetching data from the server